# Observation Labels in Kohonen Map in R

Tags: r, som, self-organizing-maps

I have built a Kohonen Map using the Kohonen library in R. Now I want to label each observation of the Mapping Plot below.

[Mapping Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FkQAM.png)

I understand that I can get the nodes coordinates with

```
som_model$grid$pts
```

but I'm not interested in the hexagonal nodes coordinates, but the observation coordinates inside the nodes.

Also, I'm not sure how to set the observation label name to these coordinates since I can´t pass a string column throught the Kohonen Map training. I dropped the label name column before training.